# Will Thai Airways provide free accommodation for transit in Bangkok?

Tags: transit, bangkok

I have connecting flight via 21 hrs transit in Bangkok. Will Thai Airways provide free accommodation for transit in Bangkok?

Comment: Not usually....

Comment: Have you asked the airline?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Thai Air does not provide transit accommodation even if you are in international first class. Also, their lounges in Suvarnabhumi Airport are closed in the wee hours (02:00 - 05:00).

There are many inexpensive (less than USD$35) hotels with free 24h shuttles close to the airport. My wife and I have used this option several times. I suggest you look at sites like agoda.com or sawasdee.com and find an airport motel. A 21 hour layover is plenty of time to get to a nearby motel, check in, sleep (deeply), and get back for your next flight.

If you don't want to clear immigration, you can check out [Louis's Tavern airside rooms](http://www.suvarnabhumiairport.com/en/1859-louis-tavern-dayroom-hotel).

I know these options are not free. The only free option is sleeping in the airport; there are places with reclining seats, but even these will get old after 21 hours (IMO).